# Cg standard function in new unity version(2018.3)

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I can't find `tex2D(sampler2D tex , float2 sz , float2 dsdx , float2 dsdy)`
this function in Unity3D(2018.3)
Where can I find it?

I read the Unity3D manual, but can't find it.
I find this function in nvidia's website about CG API

Here is the link
https://developer.download.nvidia.cn/CgTutorial/cg_tutorial_appendix_e.html

Api tells me that the function is a cg standard function, but I can't find it in "UnityCG.cginc" and "UnityStandardCore.cginc" and it does not exist in built-in functions.

```
    Pass
    {


        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma target 3.0

        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag            

        #define UNITY_SHADER_NO_UPGRADE 1

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"
        //#include "UnityStandardCore.cginc"


        struct v2f
        {
            float4 position : POSITION; 
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;

        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;


        float _Scale;
        //sampler2D unity_Lightmap;
        //float4 unity_LightmapST;


        v2f vert(appdata_full v)            
        {
            v2f o;

            o.position = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,v.vertex);



            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord,_MainTex);




            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : COLOR
        {

            float scale = 0.01;

            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex,IN.uv,float(scale,scale),float(scale,scale));

            return col;
        }


        ENDCG
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved！
Thanks
Arguments is error.
tex2D(_MainTex,IN.uv,float(scale,scale),float(scale,scale))
It's float2 ,not float